# The 'curve must be traced from left to right' requirement for the parametric arc length formula

Tags: derivatives, parametrization

I read that, for the arc length formula for curve (f(t),g(t)) to work, the curve must be traced from left to right as t varies from the lower limit to the upper limit, or dx/dt>0 in the interval.

1.What is the reason for this condition?

2. They worked out an example <3sint, 3cost> in the interval t€(0,2pi). Clearly, 3sint is not an increasing function in the given interval. However, they simply used the arc length formula as before.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for any such restriction.  The arclength formula comes from taking the length of a piecewise-linear approximation to the curve,

$$\sum_i \sqrt{(\Delta x_i)^2 + (\Delta y_i)^2} = \sum_i \sqrt{\left(\frac{\Delta x_i}{\Delta t}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\Delta y_i}{\Delta t}\right)^2} \Delta t$$

and refining it so that in the limit we get

$$\int \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2} \, dt$$

So, first of all, if we think about the geometry we see that it doesn't matter.  But we can even see this from the equation without thinking about what it means: everything of interest here is squared, sign can't possibly have any impact on anything!

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParaArcLength.aspx. But the derivation of the formula here uses the assumption that dx/dt>0

Comment: If they want to use $x$ instead of $t$, then they do need the requirement that $x$ increases when $t$ increases.  As you initially stated the question it was in terms of $t$ directly.